# How to create a html tooltip on top of image map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
<div style="width:100%" align="center">
    <img   src="./platform-logos-big.png" alt="Icons of platforms we support: Windows Linux and MacOS X" border="0" align="middle" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect"  coords="0,0,87,100" href="#Linux" alt="Click here to download Linux version of CloudClient">
        <area shape="rect" coords="88,0,195,100" href="#Windows" alt="Click here to download Windows version of CloudClient">
        <area shape="rect" coords="196,0,300,100" href="#MacOsX" alt="Click here to    download MacOsX version of CloudClient">
    </map>
</div>
<div class="WTT">
tooltipWin
</div>
<div class="LTT">
tooltipLin
</div>
<div class="MTT">
tooltipMac
</div>
```

I want to show my pure html tool tips appear on top of mouse and move fllowing it. How to do such thing with jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really you should give a common class to all the tooltips, and id to all the elements, but this works against your existing HTML.

```
$('.WTT,.LTT,.MTT').css({
    position: 'absolute'
}).hide()
$('area').each(function(i) {
    $('area').eq(i).bind('mouseover', function(e) {
        $('.WTT,.LTT,.MTT').eq(i).css({
            top: e.pageY,
            left: e.pageX
        }).show()
    })
    $('area').eq(i).bind('mouseout', function() {
        $('.WTT,.LTT,.MTT').hide()
    })
})
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/BmxR7/

Comment: Looks better with the win/lin/mac logo - the win and lin are the wrong way round though :) Like the offset, and mousemove updating - although that can just be added to mouseover event when binding. I updated with minor changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/X6P9M/

Comment: Improved the @Rella
http://jsfiddle.net/48qd5abu/

The original doesn't work in a "absolute wrapped" page (like with a theme)

Answer (score 8):

Stick a `title="your tooltip"` on your `area` tag.

Comment: That won't allow any HTML tags -- just literal text.

Answer (score 1):

You have different options here:

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip

EDIT: This link may help also: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip#Delay_and_tracking

Answer (score 0):

Regarding using jQuery UI for map > area > tooltip, you need to add:

```
$("area").tooltip({ track: true });
```

And, the styling:

```
.ui-tooltip { }
```