# Popup image on hover on an image map

Tags: html, popup, tooltip

I have an image map displaying tooltips with titles. This works perfectly, no problems there.

```html
    <html>

<map name="eyfsplayarea">
  <area shape="circle" coords="930,300,65" alt="The Mud Kitchen and Digging Zone" title="The Mud Kitchen and Digging Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="800,220,50" alt="The Niagara Channelling System, Water Table and Water Wall" title="The Niagara Channelling System, Water Table and Water Wall">
  <area shape="circle" coords="890,180,20" alt="The Sand Tray" title="The Sand Tray">
  <area shape="rect" coords="323,150,850,100" alt="A Sheltered Covered Area Linked to the Building" title="A Sheltered Covered Area Linked to the Building">
  <area shape="circle" coords="600,200,40" alt="A Roadway, Numeracy and Literacy Zone" title="A Roadway, Numeracy and Literacy Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="400,300,60" alt="Physical Development and Role Play Zone" title="Physical Development and Role Play Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="690,300,90" alt="Physical Development and Role Play Zone" title="Physical Development and Role Play Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="160,440,80" alt="The Storytellers Chair, Phonics and Mark Making Zone" title="The Storytellers Chair, Phonics and Mark Making Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="244,190,54" alt="Role Play House with Chalkboard" title="Role Play House with Chalkboard">
  <area shape="circle" coords="420,430,70" alt="Den Posts" title="Den Posts">
  <area shape="circle" coords="950,440,60" alt="The Language Lounge" title="The Language Lounge">
</map>

<img src="/EYFS-Outdoor-Play-and-Learning2.jpg" width="1621" height="725" alt="EYFS Play and Learning" usemap="#eyfsplayarea">

</html>
```

This is a standard image map as I understand with the use of tooltips. I however want to change the tooltips to either larger text blocks (to include long descriptions) or to images which will include text and graphics. I found lots of examples which I have tinkered with but they either do nothing for me or make the image a link which is viewed in a new tab when clicked on.

```html
<map id="feb1050" name="feb1050">
<area shape="rect" alt="" coords="464,170,588,263" HREF="../img/feb1050.jpg" onMouseOver="pop(event);"  onMouseOut="pop(event);"/>
...</map>
```

I feel I'm getting close but can't quite see it off. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a html tooltip on top of image map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478940/how-to-create-a-html-tooltip-on-top-of-image-map)

Comment: @Pete It could well be, sounds very similar. Unfortunately my html and overall coding skill is minimal so I don't know what half of the answers mean for that question.